# Adding variable heights with multiplier in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code does what it should perfectly, however I need to add 30% more height to the containing element `.boxy` on top of the added variable heights.

I've tried searching for ways to add a percentage to the equation, but so far I've just found vague answers or non-applicable methodologies.

```
$(".exPand a").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var postHeight = $(this).closest('.boxy').find('.articleImageThumb').height();
    var excHeight = $(this).closest('.boxy').find('.initialPostLoad').height();

    $(this).closest('.boxy').animate({height: postHeight+excHeight}, 1000);
});
```

Live output:

```
<div class="boxy">

    <div class="boxGrad"></div>

    <div class="postmetadata"></div>

    <div class="articleTitle"></div>

    <div class="rightCtrls"></div>

    <div class="ajaxBoxLoadSource"></div>

    <div class="articleImageThumb"></div>

    <div class="initialPostLoad"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: 30% more of the original height or the updating height? Just multiply by 0.3 and add the result to the height.

Comment: 30% more of the original height, plus the added variable heights as well is what I'm shooting for. How would I add the multiplier for the `0.3`?

Comment: Current Height = (Current Height * 0.3) + Current Height. Or just multiple by 1.3, either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just multiply by 1.3

```
$(this).closest('.boxy').animate({height: (postHeight * 1.3)+excHeight}, 1000);
```

Move the `* 1.3` to the appropriate place depending on which height you want 30% of.

Comment: Perfect! The operator for multiplying is where I was confused.